# Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:org.codehaus.mojo:xml-maven-plugin: 1.0:transform

Tags: maven

I am using eclipse juno, maven 3.2.2, m2e 1.4.4. I have maven multi module project and I changed it's structure to eclipse style structure by executing mvn eclipse:eclipse command.
When I'm importing this project into eclipse it is showing following error in pom.xml:

```
1. Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:org.codehaus.mojo:xml-maven-plugin:  1.0:transform
```

but xml-maven-plugin:  1.0 is available under my local repository directory. And I have attached the scrrenshot where it is showing the error when i right click my project in eclipse -->properties--->maven--->lifecycle mappinig.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: it would be better to provide a fragment of your pom.xml. It seem like  it lacks plugin configuration in build section.